# React Native: Dynamically change style with AsyncStorage and States

Tags: css, react-native, switch-statement, asyncstorage

I want to implement dark mode and black mode in my app and the way I have it is that the user toggles on dark/black mode from one class in which I want the state to be updated to all the classes, the toggle class is as followed:

AppearanceToggle Class

```
  state = {
    BlackModeValue: null,
    DarkModeValue: null
  };
  componentDidMount = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('DarkModeValue').then(value => this.setState({ DarkModeValue: JSON.parse(value) }));
    AsyncStorage.getItem('BlackModeValue').then(value => this.setState({ BlackModeValue: JSON.parse(value) }));
  };

  //AsyncStorage.setItem .........

  render() {
    return (

      <ScrollView style={[ styles.View , this.state.DarkModeValue ?  darkmode.ASView : null || this.state.BlackModeValue ? blackmode.ASView : null ]}>
          <SettingsList borderColor='#c8c7cc' defaultItemSize={50}>              
             <SettingsList.Item
              hasSwitch={true}
              switchState={this.state.DarkModeValue}
              switchOnValueChange={//Goes to asyncStorage.setItem method}
              title='Dark Mode'
            />
           <SettingsList.Item
             hasSwitch={true}
             switchState={this.state.BlackModeValue}
             switchOnValueChange={//Goes to asyncStorage.setItem method}
             title='Black Mode'
           />
          </SettingsList>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

And then in the class (which is SettingsScreen.js, this is the screen that navigates to AppearanceToggle ) that I want to .getItem and change the state is as followed:

```
  state = {
      switchValue: false,
      rated: false,
      DarkModeValue:null,
      BlackModeValue:null,
    };
  componentDidMount = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('DarkModeValue').then(value => this.setState({ DarkModeValue: JSON.parse(value) }));
    AsyncStorage.getItem('BlackModeValue').then(value => this.setState({ BlackModeValue: JSON.parse(value) }));
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={[ styles.View , this.state.DarkModeValue ?  styles.DMView : null || this.state.BlackModeValue ? styles.BMView : null ]}>
        ..........
       </ScrollView>
```

The problem I have is that when I change the switch, it affects the AppearanceToggleScreen Class instantly but not the SettingsScreen UNLESS I refresh the app. Is there a way to do it so all of them get affected instantly?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the best way to propagate it is to listen for the changes in your `AppComponent` using [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context) or root component. e.g.

So you would create a theme context like :

```
export const themes = {
  blackMode: {
    foreground: '#000000',
    background: '#eeeeee',
  },
  darkMode: {
    foreground: '#2f4f4ff',
    background: '#222222',
  },
};

export const ThemeContext = React.createContext(
  themes.darkMode // default value
)
```

;

Your `AppearanceToggle` class would have something like :

```
import {ThemeContext} from './theme-context';

class ThemedButton extends Component {
  render() {
    let props = this.props;
    let theme = this.context;
    return (
      <button
        {...props}
        style={{backgroundColor: theme.background}}
      />
    );
  }
}
ThemedButton.contextType = ThemeContext;

export default ThemedButton;
```

And then your `AppComponent` could be

```
    import {ThemeContext, themes} from './theme-context';
    import ThemedButton from './themed-button';



    function Toolbar(props) {
      // Render your customized toolbar here and bind the changeTheme function to it
    }


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   };

  componentDidMount = () => {
     AsyncStorage.getItem('selectedTheme').then(value => this.setState({ selectedTheme: JSON.parse(value) }));
  };


    this.toggleTheme = () => {
      this.setState(state => ({
        theme:
          state.theme === themes.darkMode
            ? themes.blackMode
            : themes.darkMode,
      }));
    };
  }

  render() {
    // The ThemedButton button inside the ThemeProvider
    // uses the theme from state while the one outside uses
    // the default dark theme
    return (
      <Page>
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={this.state.theme}>
          <Toolbar changeTheme={this.toggleTheme} />
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
        <Section>
          <ThemedButton />
        </Section>
      </Page>
    );
  }
}
```

For more [read](http://%20https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component)

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that in the `AppearanceToggleScreen` you're changing the state, therefore the component is rerendered (with the new theme), but because the `SettingsScreen` is already in the navigation stack (because that's where you're navigating from) the `componentDidMount` is not executing again.

Now, maybe you want to use the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context) to access globally to the values, or do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48018084/componentdidmount-function-is-not-called-after-navigation).